# MongoDB PHP header data timeout

Tags: php, mongodb

My development team is having trouble accessing a remote MongoDB database from their local development environments.

The remote Ubuntu development server is running the newest v2.4.3 of MongoDB and PHP 5.3 with the mongo-php-driver v1.3.7 built for PHP 5.3. `mongodb.conf` is nearly empty except for basic path setup. There are currently no shards or replica sets.

All team members are using OSX 10.8, PHP 5.3, and have the mongo-php-driver v1.3.7 built for PHP 5.3. Some team members use XAMPP, others are using the built-in OSX AMP stack. We test on all major desktop browsers.

Whenever a page needs to grab data from Mongo, we start by calling this connection function:

```
public static function connect($server, $db)
{
    $connection = new MongoClient(
        "mongodb://{$server}:27017", 
        array(
            "connectTimeoutMS" => 20000, 
            "socketTimeoutMS" => 20000
        )
    );

    return $connection->$db;
}
```

However, nearly 30% of page loads are experiencing the following error:

`Failed to connect to: www.development-server.com:27017: send_package: error reading from socket: Timed out waiting for header data`

It seems that a large portion of those errors occur when refreshing a page, rather than navigating to a new page, but that's more of a guess than a fact. I've checked everyone's `php.ini` file and confirmed that `default_socket_timeout = 60` is set.

The development server also hosts a copy of the site, but has never thrown the error, presumably since it's only calling localhost to get there. When I installed MongoDB locally, the errors also went away.

This really appears to be a timeout issue, but I cannot find any further settings, parameters, or configurations to adjust the expiry period. Are there any?

Comment: Is it possible to check, during such issues was the connection accepted by mongod process. You can check this in mongo logs. The log will look like : "Thu May 16 06:31:47 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:49621 #35 (2 connections now open)" Similarly you will get a log line if the connection is getting closed. I want to check if the connection is honored by mongoDB or it is not reaching that box.

Comment: I'm seeing this in the logs; when I initially load a page for the first time I see the connection `Wed May 15 21:59:25.001 [initandlisten] connection accepted from ip_address:50238 #411 (20 connections now open)` then all subsequent page loads make no log entry and pages load fine. At some random point the page fails to load and I see `Wed May 15 21:59:44.914 [conn401] end connection ip_address:49819 (19 connections now open)`. Some times I see a second connection accept without an end connection, the following page load will then fail and show the end connection.

Answer (score 1):

The response from @hernan_arg got me thinking about another possibility. Instead of relying on the one-and-only connection attempt to succeed (which seems to take forever), is it acceptable to stick the connection in a loop until it succeeds?

```
public static function connect($server, $db)
{
    $connection = null;

    try {
        $connection = new MongoClient("mongodb://{$server}");
    } catch (MongoConnectionException $e) {
        return self::connect();
        exit;
    }

    return $connection->$db;
}
```

Logging indicates that when the connection does fail, it fails quickly and the loop will establish a new connection in a much more timely manner than the infinite timeout does. Supposing the database becomes unreachable I'm assuming I can rely on PHP execution timeout to eventually kill the process.

Answer (score 0):

try connect without the port in connection or set

`array(
            "connectTimeoutMS" => -1, 
            "socketTimeoutMS" => -1
        )`

(infinite timeout)

Comment: Setting the timeouts to infinite (or even very very large) does seem to work, but requests will take a minute or more.

Answer (score 0):

The 1.4.1 release of the driver addresses some stability issues over unstable networks.

Assuming you are talking to a replicaset, the driver will discard of servers that are being unreasonably slow - rather then reattempt to connect to them the driver will now blacklist it for few seconds without throwing these exceptions upon connection (assuming we can connect to atleast one server)